# Programmatically Reading _AssemblyLocation From a VSTO Excel Workbook

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, openxml

I've got a Visual Studio Excel Workbook project. When I publish the workbook and examine the source of the workbook (I open WinZip and check custom.xml), I see the tag _AssemblyLocation, which corresponds to the publish path.

Is there a way to read _AssemblyLocation from my .NET code?

I'd like to be able to read the publish path and determine which environment (development/quality assurance/production) I'm in based on server name.

Comment: Have you tried using the ServerDocument class to access the VSTO document and read the property value that way?
Are you trying to do this at runtime or in order to modify the value during installation/setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post, "[How to get the Custom Properties of a Word Document using VSTO](http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-get-custom-properties-of-word.html)", provides a solution

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could open the xlsx using the ZipPackage class then read the XML using Xquery or xlinq etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

Comment: Kinda what I thought I'd have to do. Thanks.